# Change TeXnicCenter Block Comment Symbol

Tags: texniccenter

In TeXnicCenter, highlighting a section of text and selecting `Ctrl-Q` blocks out the section from TeX by inserting a `%` at the beginning of each line. I also use TeXnicCenter to edit Asymptote files, which uses `//` as the comment character. When I wish to block out sections of Asymptote code, I know of no other way than to insert lots of `//`'s manually.

Is there a way to modify the symbol that TeXnicCenter uses for block commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way.

I suggest to ask the TeXnicCenter support.  Perhaps there is a possibility to change it in the registry, but then you will loose `%` for TeX/LaTeX. So ask if you can define several symbols, depending on the file type you work with.

As a workaround I would use `Cntrl-Q` to insert the `%`, and afterwards use  `Cntrl+H` to change `%` to `//`.  I don't know if Asympthote uses `%` in another way ...

Comment: I'll mention it on the TeXnicCenter site. And your workaround isn't a bad idea ... I'll give it a try next time I get into Asymptote coding.